# How does c assign values to an array of pointers when it is first defined?

Tags: c

I have an array of int pointers.

```
int *ints[3];
```

What happens to memory when this array is defined? What would be the initial pointer values stored? When I try to dereference a value, I get a `segmentation fault` which tells me the values are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the storage of the array.

- If it has **static storage**, i.e. declared outside of any function or
  declared with `static` in a function, then all the elements will be NULL
- If it is declared in a function, without `static`, it will have
  **automatic storage** and the initial values will be indeterminate

The standard happens to be quite clear and helpful in this matter:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or    unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)    according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero
>     bits;

Comment: I believe it should be noted that "indeterminate" is not the same as "random". The distinction may be less significant for pointers, because using a random pointer is just as much a problem as using an indeterminate pointer, but for number types on hardware that supports trap representations, "random" can imply "any valid value", whereas an indeterminate value may be a trap representation.

Comment: It is as significant to pointers as for integer types. What traps are for integers are misaligned values for pointers. Even if by chance a pointer pointed into valid memory, it could still raise a signal when accessing the object if it isn't aligned for the base type.